# Does an unhandled runtime exception crash the whole server?

Tags: java, spring, exception, error-handling, jvm

Will an unhandled runtime exception stop the whole server (i.e. Spring Boot application) or just the specific HTTP request ?

It is true that an unhandled runtime exception will instantly shut down normal Java application, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will an unhandled runtime exception stop the whole server (i.e. Spring Boot application) or just the specific HTTP request ?

There is usually a `thread pool` in web server to handle all requests(e.g `tomcat`). Uncaught exceptions that occur in your `controller` will eventually be caught somewhere, so it will not cause the `worker thread` in the `thread pool` to be killed.

```
Tomcat#AbstractEndpoint#processSocket:

Executor executor = getExecutor();
if (dispatch && executor != null) {
    // handle request in thread poll
    executor.execute(sc);
}
```

I did a simple debug.  Assuming that an unhandle `exception` occurred in your `controller`, then the exception was actually caught by `FrameworkServlet#processRequest`. After the capture, it will be wrapped into a `NestedServletException` and continue to be thrown to the upper layer. Eventually, it will be caught and printed in `StandardWrapperValve#invoke`.

Answer (score 8):

> Will an unhandled runtime exception stop the whole server (i.e. Spring Boot application) or just the specific HTTP request ?

Just the current HTTP request ... assuming that the exception is thrown by the request thread.  (If it is thrown by a child thread, it won't even terminate the HTTP request.)

---

> It is true that an unhandled runtime exception will instantly shut down normal Java application, **right?**

Actually, not right.

An uncaught exception causes the thread on which it was thrown to terminate.  In a simple Java application where there is only one (non-daemon) "main" thread, and an uncaught exception occurs on that thread, the JVM then exit *because the last non-daemon thread has terminated*.

But if there are other threads ... the uncaught exception doesn't stop the JVM.

To illustrate, run this program:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Caught " + e);
            }
        }).start();
        throw new RuntimeException("Goodbye cruel world");
    }
}
```

When you run this, you will observe that there is a 10 second delay between the stacktrace printing (from the uncaught exception in `main`) and the program actually ending.  The JVM is waiting for the child thread to terminate.

---

This could also indirectly answer your main question ... except:

- We don't know for sure if the request threads are daemon threads or not.
- We don't know for sure that the request threads are not actually catching / handling the exceptions thrown by your request processing code.

Suffice it to say that a framework will typically *do something sensible* depending one what the thrown exception is.  For example, a framework might handle `Error` exceptions on a worker thread by attempting a shutdown ... on the basis that the error may have put the JVM into a potentially unsafe / non-recoverable state.

Answer (score 4):

### Just the thread in question

An unhandled `RuntimeException` will kill the thread, not the application. Usually each HTTP request is handled by its own thread, so nothing else in the server should be affected. I don’t know how the server handles the dead thread. A wise move would probably be creating a new thread for upcoming requests.

Only when *all* threads (except so-called demon threads) are terminated, will your Spring Boot application stop. This in turn means that in an application that isn’t threaded — one that has everything running in the main thread — an uncaught exception (`RuntimeException` or some other type) *will* bring the whole program down.

In most applications it matters *which* thread is killed. Your application probably has more threads handling HTTP requests and can spawn new ones as needed. In this case a thread death will hardly be noticed except by the user having sent this HTTP request. Other threads are probably more vital to the functioning of the server, and such a thread being killed, while not stopping the server completely, will stop it from working properly. For a different example, if the event dispatching thread in a desktop application is killed by an exception, the application can no longer accept user input.

### Try it out for yourself

It doesn’t take a lot to try it out. The following program spawns a thread that throws an unhandled exception.

```
public class DemoUnhandledException {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Thread(() -> { throw new RuntimeException("Demo"); }).start();
        TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
        System.out.println("A minute later the main thread is still alive and well");
    }

}
```

Let the program run for a full minute to get the full output, which is:

> ```
> Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Demo
>   at ovv.so.exception.DemoUnhandledException.lambda$0(DemoUnhandledException.java:8)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> A minute later the main thread is still alive and well
> ```

### Link

[How uncaught exceptions are handled in Java](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/exceptions/exceptions_uncaught_handler.shtml) on Javamex